# How to with create a compoundPredicate with both "OR" and "AND"

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the following 3 categories fetched, but want to add a "AND" predicate to narrow the results, where the "mark" is on.

```
NSMutableArray *questionNumberArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Fetch questions
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =
[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Questions"];

//building the predicate with selected category
NSMutableArray *parr = [NSMutableArray array];

if ([cat0str length]){
    [parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question.category CONTAINS[c] %@",cat0str]];
}
if ([cat1str length]){
    [parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question.category CONTAINS[c] %@",cat1str]];
}
if ([cat2str length]){
    [parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question.category CONTAINS[c] %@",cat2str]];
}

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:parr];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

---

```
    NSPredicate *markPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question.mark == 1"];
}
```

//I'd like to do something like that:

```
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [compoundPredicate && markPredicate];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:finalPredicate];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:compoundPredicate, markPredicate, nil]];
```

or, using the "modern Objective-C" syntax for container literals:

```
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                     @[compoundPredicate, markPredicate]];
```